# Qml ComboBox проблема с popup

Tags: qt5, qml

Подскажите как добавить изображение в всплывающий список ComboBox

```
Button {
    id: control

    ColumnLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent

        Image {
            id: name
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            source: "qrc:/qml/image/icon/list.png"
            fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
        }

        TextST {
            id: lable
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            text                : "lableText"
            font.pixelSize      : 16
        }
    }

    ComboBox{
        id: comboBox
        visible: false
        model: ["test1", "test2", "test3"]

        anchors.left    : parent.left
        anchors.bottom  : parent.bottom

        popup: Popup { ??? }

    }
}
```

Чтобы понятнее было, идея в следующем:
Нажимаем на кнопку и появляется всплывающие окно в котором список пунктов (картинка + текст).

Comment: в C++ есть QPushButton::setMenu, выглядит как кнопка с треугольником справа, при нажатии выпадает меню, может и в Qml так можно...

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-customize.html#customizing-combobox

Answer (score 0):

Вот тут написано о кастомизации ComboBox.
В элементе ListView (Popup) прописать делегата и добавить туда текст и картинку, как и в обычном ListView

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-customize.html#customizing-combobox